# How to prove $|\text{Aut(G)}|=2\implies |G|=3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, automorphism-group

As suggested in the title I'm trying to prove $|G|=3$ given that $|\text{Aut}(G)|=2.$

First I thought that: for an automorphism, we have no choice for the identity element because the identity must go to the identity and for the other non-identity elements there are exactly $2$ permutations. So if $|G|=n$ then $(n-1)!=2\implies n=3$.

But I realized that the orders of elements are being preserved by automorphisms.  So *any* permutation is not allowed for considering the automorphisms.

Please help me to get the idea of the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to prove is incorrect, since each of the cyclic groups $C_3,C_4,$ and $C_6$ has automorphism group containing exactly $2$ elements. So it cannot be the case that $|\textrm{Aut}(G)|=2$ implies $|G|=3$.